# Can you disable email notifications for a blog post saved as a draft?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, blog, draft

In SP 2010 Foundation, I have a blog setup to allow contributors to post as a draft. However, all of the users that have alerts setup for posts receive an email when these drafts are created. That defeats the purpose of drafts as you don't want the general audience to see the content of the post until it's actually published. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a view only showing published items and change the alerts to be on changes to an item that appears in that view.

[image]

Note that the list needs at least one view with a filter for that option to appear

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask a side question. Is it possible to change the "Blog Tools" section's "Manage Posts" link? I'd prefer to tackle this another way, to leave what the users' view is for alerts "All Posts" but with a filter of Approval Status is equal to "Approved" only ...and to just change the Manage Posts to a view that shows all Approval Statuses. It seems more manageable that way, as opposed to having all users change the view their alert is based on (i.e. how to enforce that?). I'm sure, though, that I may be missing something. Thank you.

Comment: The BlogAdminWebPart is 100% hardcoded, but you could create your own web part. But also keep in mind that Alerts isn't the intented way for people to keep up to date with new Approved blog posts, the RSS feed is.